# Converting C++ into Python code, Looping through directories and getting the timestamp from a file?

Tags: python, loops, timestamp, filesize, directory

I have been given the task of converting a C++ script into python script. The aim of the script is to loop through all the directories (by start and end date) in the mediaDB and calculate what size the zipfile is going to be.  I am stuck at getting the for loop to go through the directories, its so different in python from C++ which i have more experience in. Could anyone offer any suggestions?

C++ Code

```
// This will loop over each core files directory and sum the file size.
    directory_iterator dirIt(mediaDBCoreFilesDir);
for (directory_iterator dirIt(mediaDBCoreFilesDir);dirIt!=directory_iterator();dirIt++)
```

Also if anyone has any ideas as to how to get the last update timestamp from a file in python that would be very much appreciated.  The C++ code is:

```
// Get the last update timestamp from the file
std::time_t t = last_write_time(*dirIt);
ptime fileTimeStamp =  from_time_t(t);
```

EDIT: i am trying to write a for statement firstly that loops over all directories and sums up the file size of them.  I dont need to edit, delete or print  any directories, just get the file sizes. Is it then more appropriate to use os.walk and os.path.getsize?

Secondly, i need to retrieve the last updated timestamp from the files.
Tho i dont really understand this process of getting the timestamp.

Comment: Did you read the `os` module yet?  Almost everything you want is in `os.walk()` and `os.path.getmtime()`.  It would help if you could read those module and update your question to be more specific about what you read and didn't understand.

Comment: Is it best to use os.listdir or os.walk?

Comment: "best"?  Please provide your working definition of "best" so we know what you think is important.  The two functions do very different things, so "best" is hard to answer without real, substantial details on what you think you're doing.  Also.  Please **update** the question to clarify what you need to know.

Comment: "`os.walk` and `os.path.getsize`"?  They do different things.  It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: yes, i need to go through all the directories and get the size of each of them

Comment: "i need to go through all the directories and get the size of each of them".  Fine.  What part of that is confusing you?  What have you tried?  You have Python.  You can type things at the `>>>` prompt.  Please explain what -- specifically -- is confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`os.path.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk) or [`glob.glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) for enumerating files in a directory subtree, and [`os.stat`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) (or `os.lstat`) for getting the timestamp of the most recent modification.